# Expressing surds in different forms

Tags: substitution

I know this might get taken down for being a dumb question but I'm not exactly a genius when it comes to maths. So the question is I need to express 6/√2 in the form of a√b and a and b both need to be positive integers. Help me please.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt2$.

Comment: You become a genius by trying yourself before asking others to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do here is to multiply and divide by $\surd 2$ and use the fact that $(\surd 2)(\surd 2)=2$,
$$
\frac{6}{\surd 2}=\frac{6\surd 2}{(\surd 2)(\surd 2)}=\frac{6\surd 2}{2}=3\surd 2.
$$